# Combine some items in list

Tags: python

I have list like this,

```
arr = [{"type":"A","name":"1"},
 {"type":"B","name":"2"},
 {"type":"B","name":"3"},
 {"type":"C","name":"4"},
 {"type":"B","name":"5"},
 {"type":"B","name":"6"},
 {"type":"D","name":"7"},
 {"type":"B","name":"8"},
 {"type":"B","name":"9"},]]
```

I want to combine type `B` like this below

Adding `pages` key

```
[{"type":"A","name":"1"},
 {"type":"B","pages":[
    {"type":"B","name":"2"},
    {"type":"B","name":"3"}]},
 {"type":"C","name":"4"},
 {"type":"B","pages":[
   {"type":"B","name":"5"},
   {"type":"B","name":"6"}
 ]},
 {"type":"D","name":"7"},
 {"type":"B","pages":[
   {"type":"B","name":"8"},
   {"type":"B","name":"9"}
 ]}
]
```

I try to do this with loop,

However, still struggling..

Please give me some ideas.

```
result = []
first = False
for i in arr:
    if i['type'] == "B":
        if first == False:
            first = True
            i['pages'] = []
            i['pages'].append(i)
        else:
            i['pages'].append(i)
    else:
        result.append(i)
        flg = False
print(result)
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code? "Still struggling" isn't a useful error description.

Comment: You listed the expected output, maybe share the actual one as well. Also this could ebenfit you https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-group-a-list-by-values-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution using `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

result = []
for key, group in groupby(arr, key=lambda x: x['type']):
    group = list(group)
    if len(group) > 1:
        result.append({'type': key, 'pages': group})
    else:
        result.append(group[0])

from pprint import pprint
pprint(result)
```

Output:

```
[{'name': '1', 'type': 'A'},
 {'pages': [{'name': '2', 'type': 'B'}, {'name': '3', 'type': 'B'}],
  'type': 'B'},
 {'name': '4', 'type': 'C'},
 {'pages': [{'name': '5', 'type': 'B'}, {'name': '6', 'type': 'B'}],
  'type': 'B'},
 {'name': '7', 'type': 'D'},
 {'pages': [{'name': '8', 'type': 'B'}, {'name': '9', 'type': 'B'}],
  'type': 'B'}]
```

Comment: just as an FYI this won't work if a `B` group has a length of 1 based on your condition, also this is not a proper use of `groupby` as the data is expected to be pre-sorted on the grouping key, if the data were sorted beforehand (on anything other then the identity key), the output would be way off

Comment: @gold_cy The data needs to be sorted if you actually want to groupby across the whole list. Note that the output in the question asks to group consecutive runs, so no sorting is needed... Also there is no group of 1 B in the question so it's hard to say what the expected output is...

Comment: @gold_cy Yes, this is abusing the behavior of groupby if the iterable isn't sorted. This produces determinable results.

Comment: Thank you it works for me now. It dosen't work when I have only 1 row B but in my use case I don`t use 1 row B